# Is there a way to backup old iOS Simulators for future Xcode Mac App Store Updates?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, mac-app-store

I've installed the Xcode 4.3.2 using the Mac App Store when it first arrived.  So far there have been a couple of updates to the application itself, and I noticed that after the application update the older iOS Simulators I have installed (4.3 and 5.0) are gone and have to be re-downloaded.  While downloading these hasn't been an issue yet, it's quite inconvenient to have to download over a 1 GB of tools after each Xcode update.  Is there a way to backup these simulators so that I can just copy them back over once there is another Xcode Mac App Store update?

Comment: Any ideas?  The latest 4.3.3 update did the exact same thing.  After the update I needed to download 1 GB of simulators again (4.3 & 5.0).

Comment: it's really annoying to see old simulator's gone. I am also looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

All the previous versions of the Simulators are stored in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

So you should just be able to back up that folder, or copy the specific simulators you want.